# Delphi XE7 BDE Alias - setting it at run time?

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi XE7, and one of our large legacy applications still uses the BDE extensively with Paradox tables. I know the BDE is deprecated, but we have no choice with this app.

This app currently sets up the BDE aliases at run time, at startup. It uses the standard default Session provided by the BDE, and it uses "TSession.AddStandardAlias" to add an alias, and refers to many tables defined in data modules.

I now have the need to be able to change the folder path an alias refers to later in the running of the app, but have found problems with it. Basically, it seems to work, but after the alias is changed it somehow still refers to the previous path. Even "TSession.GetAliasParams" reports the new path, but then an error occurs in Bde.DBTables because it's trying to access the previous path, which no longer exists.

Given the app is large, I've reproduced a similar problem in the following sample project. If someone is willing to try this, it's a very simple app with just the main form. You need to setup two folders, and drop any Paradox table into one folder, when then specify that path to that folder in the Edit box and then press the "Set Alias Path" button, that will set the alias, and then it writes to a label below the button that tells you the path the alias refers to. Then the "Find table" button and edit box looks for the existence of a table using "TSession.GetTableNames".

The simplest way to do it is to setup two folders "C:\TEMP\testBDE\path1" and "C:\TEMP\testBDE\path2", and drop any Paradox table into path1, when you run the app press the "Set Alias Path" button, and then press the "Find table" button and it will report the table exists.

[Main form of sample app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxCvl.png)

Then change the alias to refer to path2, which is empty, and it reports it pointing path2, but also reports the table exists. It's easy then to move the table from path1 to path2, and it will then report the table does not exist.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Bde.DBTables;

const
  myAlias = 'ALIAS1';

function getPathFromAlias(tempAlais : String ): String;
var
  MyStringList : TStringList;
  i, k: integer;
  tempStr, newDirectory: String;
begin
  newDirectory:='';
  MyStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Session.GetAliasParams(tempAlais,MyStringList);
    { fill stringlist with driver names }
    for i := 0 to MyStringList.count-1 do
    begin
      tempStr:= uppercase(trim(MyStringList.Strings[i]));
      k := pos('PATH=', tempStr);
      if k > 0 then
      begin
        delete(tempStr,1, k+4);
        newDirectory:=tempStr;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    MyStringList.Free;
  end;
  result:=newDirectory;
end;

procedure setAliases( apath : String);
var
  MyStringList : TStringList;
begin
(*
  MyStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    MyStringList.Add( 'PATH='+apath);
    MyStringList.Add( 'ENABLE BCD=FALSE');
    MyStringList.Add( 'DEFAULT DRIVER=PARADOX');
    Session.ConfigMode := cmSession;
    if Session.IsAlias( myAlias) then
      Session.ModifyAlias( myAlias, MyStringList)
    else
      Session.AddStandardAlias( myAlias, apath, 'PARADOX');
    Session.ConfigMode := cmSession;
  finally
    MyStringList.Free;
  end;
*)
  Session.ConfigMode := cmSession;
  if Session.IsAlias( myAlias) then
    Session.DeleteAlias( myAlias);
  Session.AddStandardAlias( myAlias, apath, 'PARADOX');
  Session.ConfigMode := cmSession;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  setAliases( Edit1.Text);
  Label1.Caption := getPathFromAlias( myAlias);
end;

function TableExists(const aDataBaseName, aTableName:string): Boolean;
var
  TableNames: TStringList;
begin

  TableNames:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    Session.GetTableNames(aDatabaseName,'',True,False,TableNames);
    Result:=(TableNames.IndexOf(aTableName)<>-1);
  finally
    TableNames.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  temps : String;
  myTable : TTable;
begin

  if TableExists( myAlias, Edit2.Text) then
    Label2.Caption := 'Exists'
  else
    Label2.Caption := 'Not found'
end;

end.
```

Comment: what is the operating system? what is the full path to the file containing BDE aliases ?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's Windows 7. I'm not using the BDE config file, the aliases in the actual legacy app are created at run time, and the paths they refer to come from another app that launches the legacy app. These paths are based on the original installation folder.

Comment: Vista+ has so-called "virtual storage" so part of files are not really lying where application reads and writes them. Use tool like SysInternals Process Monitor and intercept file I/O log when your app save/read aliases, check the filenames that they match, then try to see if two aliases files ( "idapi32.cfg" by default AFAIR )  exist on disk, in default place and in Virtual Store - they may overlap. Also try to run your app "as admin" - that is with "UAC elevation" - which temporarily de-activates Virtual Store for the process AFAIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **Close** the session before changing the alias properties and then **Open** it again afterward:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Session.Close;

  setAliases( Edit1.Text);
  Label1.Caption := getPathFromAlias( myAlias);

  Session.Open;
end;
```

The problem is not that path changes are not recognised but that such changes are not recognised if they are made to *aliases that are in use* as this scenario in your test program illustrates:

1. Button 1 clicked: path is changed
2. Button 2 clicked: Table is **not** found
3. Change path in Edit 1 to refer back to original alias path
4. Use Button 1 to reset path
5. Button 2 clicked: Table is **still not** found

i.e. if the first thing you do is change the path, then the alias does indeed reflect that changed path.  The issue is that once you have used an alias, changes to the path are **not** subsequently reflected.

By closing the session and re-opening it, you ensure that the alias is properly "reset".

In your actual application this may cause knock-on effects with database connections needing to be re-opened after closing and re-opening the session, although this is speculation on my part.

### Alternative Approach

As an alternative to closing the session in order to modify an alias at runtime, another approach might be to add a new alias with the required properties and redirect the database connections to that alternate alias.

This also will obviously entail disconnecting and reconnecting all databases and queries that are redirected to this alternate alias.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had read in the help that it is not recommended to close the default BDE session, that's why I hadn't done that, but what you said makes sense. Perhaps I'm best to create my own session, rather than use the default session?

Comment: However, I was hoping to avoid creating my own session, only because I worry what implications that may have in the large legacy app. Perhaps I have no other choice.

Comment: @DavidT at least in `BDE Administrator` GUI there is a specific button "apply changes" that "commits" adjustments, stores aliases file onto disk, and no changes are seen by other apps without it. So there is to be similar concept in your app actions. Whether it is closing session or there is some another method to "apply changes" I don't know.

Comment: I think because the existing app only had aliases setup once at startup, and never changed, it was never a problem, but now that we need to change it at run time, it is a problem. I will follow your suggestion and research how changes can be applied. Thanks

Comment: I tried closing the default Session, changing the alias, and then re-opening the Session, as you suggested, and that seemed to work. I'll have to think whether I should do that given the Help does not recommend it, but at least it's a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: An alternative approach might be to create an alternate alias in the session and switch your connections to that alias, rather than modifying the properties of an existing alias, but this is likely to involve more work (hard to say whether extra work is prohibitive in your specific application).

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you see any mention of it not being recommended to close the default session ?  I don't see anything relating to this in the docs.  There is nothing special about the default session as far as I know, other than that it is the default.  Closing this session should be no more problematic than closing any other session.  You just need to be aware that closing the session (*any* session) will close all active queries and database connections in that session, which will need to be re-established/re-opened, as noted in the answer.

Comment: I found the comment here:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Activating_a_Session
The second Note says:
"Note: You cannot set Active to False for the default session at design time. While you can close the default session at run time, it is not recommended."
I will look into the possibility of creating an alternate alias and see how difficult it is to switch to that at run time, given the existing code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is simply "not recommended" due to the fact that unless otherwise specified database objects are all placed in the default session so closing that default session *without understanding the consequences* is likely to lead to unexpected problems, not that you shouldn't do it under any circumstances.  If there were specific reasons to not support closing the default session this could easily have been prevented in the Close method itself, but it isn't.  But if you are concerned or do run into difficulties then the alternate alias idea might be worth considering.

Comment: I've tested adding additional aliases as required in the sample app, rather than closing the default Session, and it worked. So, I'll investigate doing the same in the actual legacy app, I feel more comfortable following this line, and I think it minimizes the changes. Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @Deltics If you could update your answer to include the alternative of adding aliases as required, I could accept your answer. Thanks.